# Ng-select lib: How i change the primary color?

Tags: css, angular, npm, colors, angular-ngselect

The primary color is #3f51b5, an blue dark color, but i want to customize this color.
My research I discovery samples that:

`::ng-deep .ng-select.ng-select-focused .ng-select-container * { color: $colorP !important; }`

but the code above just part of the color I want to change.
How i change the primary color in the all code?

I just found code snippets that changed parts of the problem, but ended up creating others, I would like to know if there is a way to change all the color at once.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, you can change colors of your application by updating the theme file, typically located in the src/styles.scss or .css

Try this : or your selector, the idea to put the overriding style in the main file

```
yourSelector {
    color: yourColor;
}
```